# What is a good Open Source game engine for a beginner?

Tags: java, c++, qt

I want to develop a game and I am at a beginner level.

When I searched for game engines on Google a long list was returned (e.g. Delta 3D, Panda 3D)

Then I looked at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) and it also showed a very large list.

I am not sure which engine to choose.

Please suggest a good game engine and some good tutorial or a good ebook.

I am experienced in C++, QT4, Java and Python(at very initial level).

**If the game engine supports Linux platform then I will be very happy.**

Comment: Do you want your game to be 2d or 3d?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out OGRE3D. It's totally cross-platform and it's a commercial quality game engine- for example, the indie game Torchlight uses OGRE3D and it was a huge success.

Comment: Actually OGRE is just a 3D graphics engine.

Comment: I know. In comparison to the rest of the systems, it's by far the most important/hardest component.

Answer (score 2):

Asuming you are looking at 3D, I'd personally recommend [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/).

It's well designed, open source, has great performance, very easy to use (for a 3D engine...) and under active development.

Whatever you choose then good luck - just be aware that you have a long journey ahead if you want to actually successfully develop a 3D game :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you can look at the [Cube](http://cubeengine.com/) which you can [download from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cube/).

Since you are a beginner, I suggest you look at linear algebra. A very good source for this is the [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/#Linear%20Algebra). That you will be in a much better position to evaluate the needs you have for a game-engine.

Answer (score 1):

Java:

[jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/)

Python:

[pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) (though not really a game engine)

Answer (score 0):

Most all of the code for Quake engine, but not the content, has been made public. So you can play around with that engine to see if it's up to you specifications (the Quake 1, Quake 2, and Quake 3 engines have all been released). Quake 1, 2, and 3 all support the Linux platform.

Also, while the Source Engine isn't open source, a great deal of the source code is available through the Source SDK. It's very easy to modify and you should definitely consider working with it. However, Source is Windows and Mac only.

[This resource](http://psykor3.quakedev.com/tutorial1.html) deals with the Quake 3 engine and is a bit outdated, but I'm sure it'll suit you just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to qualify your question with what sort of game you're trying to build. Not all game engines are created equal for this :)

So, just for brevity's sake, if you are after building a 2D game, the Gluon game creation and distribution framework ( http://gluon.gamingfreedom.org/ ) may well be the sort of thing you're looking for. Also because it's built using Qt, with which you mention you are already familiar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 2D, then the GLib engine (theglibengine.wordpress.com) is probably a good start. I must warn you though, it's new and still a bit buggy. It's written Java. For 3D, I'd recommend JMonkeyEngine (for NetBeans) or Ardor3D (for Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

PLIB is a useful engine for Linux users. It uses a program called OpenGL to operate, so you may need that first, and it's a tiny bit complicated to install, but there are tutorials on that and on C+++ script writing. Perfect 3D engine for Linux.